# FasterXml Jackson serialize properly but doesn't call deserialize on ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, mapper

I'm on a project that require FasterXML and ZonedDateTime. It is mandatory to not use annotation like `using=Deserializer.class` because we want to keep the same format of date on all the project.

That being said, I come here to ask help because I can't figure out why my Deserializer is instanciate but its method `deserialize()` is not call ...

Here my configuration :

The serializer :

```
public class ZonedDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    /**
     * The date time formatter to use
     */
    DateTimeFormatter dtf;

    /**
     * Instanciate a new serializer
     *
     * @param dtf The datetime formatter
     */
    public ZonedDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeSerializer()");
        this.dtf = dtf;
    }


    @Override
    public void serialize(ZonedDateTime dateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeSerializer::serialize()");
        if (null != dateTime) {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(dateTime.format(dtf));
        }
    }
}
```

The deserializer :

```
public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    /**
     * The date time formatter to use
     */
    DateTimeFormatter dtf;

    /**
     * Instanciate a new deserializer
     *
     * @param dtf The datetime formatter
     */
    public ZonedDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter dtf) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(dtf, "Date time formatter is null");
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeDeserializer()");
        this.dtf = dtf;
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTimeDeserializer::deserialize()");
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(jsonParser.getText(), dtf);
    }
}
```

This two add to the mapper in a mapper provider :

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfigurator implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public JacksonConfigurator() {

        System.out.println("new ObjectMapperResolver()");
        DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

        SimpleModule xxxModule = new SimpleModule("XXXX", new Version(2, 0, 0, null))
                .addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(sdf))
                .addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeDeserializer(sdf));

        mapper.registerModule(xxxModule);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And register here in a glassfish jersey ResourceConfig;

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationRessourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    /**
     * Define application config
     */
    public ApplicationRessourceConfig() {

        // File to parse
        packages(true, "com.xxx.xxx");

        // CDI to Jersey
        register(new WebServiceBinder());

        // Jackson config
        register(new JacksonConfigurator());

        // Role
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

I can't test it in production or development until the tests are ok. So I make the test like :

```
public class xxxTest extends JerseyTest {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ...
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(...);

        config.register(new JacksonConfigurator());

        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void xxx() {
        ...
        response.bufferEntity();
        response.readEntity(EntityWithZonedDateTime.class);
        ...
    } 
}
```

When I was using the annotation `@JsonDeserializer` on each ZonedDateTime property it worked perfectly but now, the `Serializer` constructor is logged, `serialize()` is logged too, event the `Deserializer` constructor is logged, but not the `deserialize()` method.

Instead I have :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.ZonedDateTime] from String value ('2012-06-30T12:30:40.000+0000'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@3af4e0bf; line: 1, column: 46] (through reference chain: com.xxx.xxx.resources.utils.Xxxx["beginDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:843)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:277)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:284)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1150)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:153)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:144)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1408)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:858)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:777)
```

At 2pm, it will be 48 hours I'm on it. Impossible to know why the mapper doesn't try to desiarilize with the deserializer and it fallback on the string. And guess what ... The fasterxml wiki is down ... Any clue is welcome.

--- EDIT ---

For information, the entity sent in request look like :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class XxxOutput {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    public static class XxxJson {

        /* ---------- Properties ---------- */
        public BigInteger id;

        public String name;

        public String definition;

        public ZonedDateTime beginDate;

        public ZonedDateTime endDate;

        public ZonedDateTime creationDate;

        public ZonedDateTime lastUpdate;

        public Map<String, BigInteger> relateds;

        /* ---------- Constructor ---------- */
        public XxxJson() {}

        public XxxJson(... all args ...) {
            this.id = id;
            ...
            this.relateds = relateds;
        }
        /* ---------- Useful methods ---------- */
        public XxxJson addRelated(final Xxx related) {
            ...
            // add the Xxx.id to the list
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id.toString();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply using the [Jackson JSR-310 module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)? It [supports `ZonedDateTime`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/InstantDeserializer.java) and is available [on Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes thanks, it's probably a good idea but we have to communicate with other API and the dateformat have to be : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` that I think I can't set with `new JSR310Module()` :/

Comment: That would seem to be a fairly critical part of the question then, no?

Comment: The module I linked is Open source. Take their (working) code and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks again Boris, I will try that, but I really think that the problem is the integration of the bellowing code in the jersey test. The registering in some words. And yes you're right, I should have highlighted the format problem in the question.

Comment: Wow, I'll bring me the answer  ... FasterXml has no ZonedDateTimeDeserializer :
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JSR310Module.java
What can I do to make json parser to call the deserializer when encounter a ZonedDateTime ???

Comment: I tried your code and it works pretty fine though. Can you please update your question with the object which you try to deserialize to, where you ZonedDateTime property? Anyway the messge you get says that ZonedDateTime  does not have a default constructor so Jackson is unable to create an instance of it

Comment: Really @vtorosyan ? It works for you in the Jersey Test ? Anyway I had the entity class as you ask. It worked with the annotation @JsonDeserializer(using=ZonedDateTimeDeserializer.class) so it can't be a default constructor of ZonedDateTime, can it be ?

Comment: The line `addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, InstantDeserializer.ZONED_DATE_TIME);` doesn't stand out?

Comment: Nope, I have to format the date. But it's really not the problem. After investigation, if I use the basic mapper (the one which format the zoneddatetime in an array with day, month, year ...) the deserialization is not done correctly, so I think the problem is somewhere else :/